# Laravel 5 with Sentry RouteServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel-5, upgrade, cartalyst-sentry

Trying to upgrade to Laravel and following this [Laravel 5 upgrade](http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0)

But when it comes to Filter routes for Sentry. I get this error:

```
FatalErrorException in RouteServiceProvider.php line 38: Class 'App\Providers\Session' not found
```

Related to this copied and pasted from previous L4 filter:

```
 namespace App\Providers;
 use Cartalyst\Sentry\Facades\Laravel\Sentry;
 use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

 class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
   protected $namespace = NULL;   //using composer

   public function boot(Router $router)
   {
     parent::boot($router);

     Route::filter('Sentry', function(){
       if (!Sentry::check()) {
          Session::put('loginRedirect', Request::url());
          return Redirect::guest('login');
        } 
     });
   }
 }
```

The 'Session' is the issue. 
Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `Session`.

```
use Session;
```

Or prepend it with a backslash

```
\Session::put('loginRedirect', Request::url());
```

The same goes for `Request` and `Redirect`

Answer (score 0):

`Session` facade exists under global namespace. Since your file is under `App\Providers` namespace, you have to use `\Session::put('loginRedirect', Request::url());` instead of `Session::put('loginRedirect', Request::url());`.